# How to configure maven and intellij to include parameters compiler flag for both groovy and java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy, jackson

Hey I am writing this since I spent some time trying to configure **Jackson's** ObjectMapper to work without `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` annotations on my DTOs. The result I wanted to achieve is to be able to run Spock's tests (groovy) in both intellij and in console with maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this issue is resolved: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125737 intellij automatically picks up below maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
      <testCompilerArgument>-parameters</testCompilerArgument>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also if you want to use Spock for testing in groovy you need following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

plus additional information:

1. At the moment I was writing this there was only one version of groovy compiler that worked for me: 2.5.0-alpha-1
2. maven-compiler-plugin version I used was 3.7.0. Version 3.1 did not work at all. I did not try others.

I hope this saves someone some time :)